# miles for multiple trucks python array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm new to python and programming in general. This problem is asking for a parallel array for 10 trucks , an array for miles, an array for gallons, and another for costs per gallon.  If anyone has a recommendation on helpful sites or videos I could take a look at to figure python out that would be awesome! Thanks for the help in advance. So far I have this..

```
size = 10
miles[size]
gallons[size]
costs[size]

for index == 1 in size - 1:
    print("Enter the miles, gallons, and costs of fuel for truck 1.", index + 1)
miles[index] = int(input("miles:" )
gallons[index] = int(input("gallons:" )
costs[index] = int(input("costs:" )
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? Error, unexpected output?

Comment: im getting an invalid syntax error for line 6 ==

Comment: That's not how Python lists work - you don't size them up-front like arrays in other languages. Also, indentation is important - your `input` is **outside** your `for` loop. Try following a tutorial, e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: The obvious issues here are that your for loop should be something like `for index in range(size)`. Then the print should be something like `print("Enter ... for truck {}".format(index + 1))`.

Comment: does it seem correct so far? would a list be easier seeing as i am using python

Comment: Also, let us know what problem you're trying to solve.  Do you want to display the list of trucks and fuel costs?  Or, are you trying to calculate the price per gallon?

Comment: @Jesuisme I want to display the miles, gallons, costs per gallon for each truck at the end of the code, which I pretty much know how to do. I'm just having problem figuring out the **for loop**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
size = 10
miles = []
gallons = []
costs = []

for index in range(size):
    print("Enter the miles, gallons, and costs of fuel for truck {}.".format(index + 1))
    miles.append(int(input("miles:")))
    gallons.append(int(input("gallons:")))
    costs.append(int(input("costs:")))
```

There were a few issues with your original version:

1. As stated in the comments, you don't (generally) initialise a Python list to start at a certain size, instead you create it empty and then add as much stuff into it as you need.
2. The `for` loop need to be in the form of `for <var> in <iterable>`. Then you can use `range(x)` as your iterable, in Python 2.7 `range` will return a list of all the numbers in that range, in Python 3 it returns an iterator (which is more memory efficient). `range(3)` will allow you to iterate over 0, 1 and 2 (for a total of 3 iterations).
3. The print statement can be tidied up a bit. By using `<string>.format()` you can make the output a lot easier. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples for the full documentation.

Comment: for some reason line 9 **gallons** is giving me an invalid syntax

Comment: There were 3 `(` but only 2 `)` on all those input lines. I've fixed this but you should have spotted it! Your original code had a similar issue ;-)

Comment: I see what you are saying. Thanks for the help everyone